Google Health Connect integration in Java project issues
I am trying to integrate Google Health Connect APIs into android native app written in Java in order to track step count however I am having issues. For some reason I am having hard time integrating all Google Health Connect methods written in Kotlin in Fragments and activities of Java project.
I have followed this steps Get started with Health Connect and I have modified code provided by google but still no success.
Does anyone have an experience of integration of this new API suggested by Google in Android app written in java?
Just in case here is my code
HealthConnectManager (Kotlin)
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import androidx.health.connect.client.HealthConnectClient
import androidx.health.connect.client.aggregate.AggregateMetric
import androidx.health.connect.client.aggregate.AggregationResultGroupedByPeriod
import androidx.health.connect.client.permission.HealthPermission
import androidx.health.connect.client.records.ExerciseSessionRecord
import androidx.health.connect.client.records.SleepSessionRecord
import androidx.health.connect.client.records.StepsRecord
import androidx.health.connect.client.request.AggregateGroupByPeriodRequest
import androidx.health.connect.client.time.TimeRangeFilter.Companion.between
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import java.time.Duration.between
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.LocalTime
import java.time.Period
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.util.TimeZone
import kotlin.time.Duration

data class DataRecord(
    val metricValue: String,
    val dataType: DataType,
    val fromDatetime: String,
    val toDatetime: String
)

class HealthConnectManager(private val context: Context)  {
        private var healthConnectClient: HealthConnectClient? = null
        val PERMISSIONS = setOf(
            HealthPermission.getReadPermission(StepsRecord::class),
        )

        private val dateTimeFormatter: DateTimeFormatter =
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")

    fun checkForHealthConnectInstalled(context: Context): Int {
        val availabilityStatus =
            HealthConnectClient.getSdkStatus(context, "com.google.android.apps.healthdata")
        when (availabilityStatus) {
            HealthConnectClient.SDK_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                Log.w("HealthConnectUtils", "Health Connect SDK is unavailable on this device.")
            }
            HealthConnectClient.SDK_UNAVAILABLE_PROVIDER_UPDATE_REQUIRED -> {
                Log.w("HealthConnectUtils", "Health Connect SDK needs an update.")
            }
            HealthConnectClient.SDK_AVAILABLE -> {
                Log.i("HealthConnectUtils", "Health Connect SDK is available.")
                healthConnectClient = HealthConnectClient.getOrCreate(context)
            }
        }
        return availabilityStatus
    }

        suspend fun checkPermissions(): Boolean {
            val granted = healthConnectClient?.permissionController?.getGrantedPermissions()
            return granted?.containsAll(PERMISSIONS) == true
        }

        suspend fun readStepsForInterval(interval: Long): List<DataRecord> {
            return readAggregateDataForInterval(interval, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, StepsRecord.COUNT_TOTAL)
        }

        private suspend fun <T : Any> readAggregateDataForInterval(interval: Long, dataType: DataType, metric: AggregateMetric<T>): List<DataRecord> {
            val startTime: ZonedDateTime = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).minusDays(interval - 1)
            val endTime = LocalDateTime.now().atZone(TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId()).minusMinutes(1).plusSeconds(59)
            val response = healthConnectClient?.aggregateGroupByPeriod(
                AggregateGroupByPeriodRequest(
                    metrics = setOf(metric),
                    timeRangeFilter = between(startTime.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(), endTime.toLocalDateTime()),
                    timeRangeSlicer = Period.ofDays(1)
                )
            )
            return parseAggregateResponse(response, startTime, endTime, dataType, metric)
        }

        private fun <T : Any> parseAggregateResponse(
            response: List<AggregationResultGroupedByPeriod>?,
            startTime: ZonedDateTime,
            endTime: ZonedDateTime,
            dataType: DataType,
            metric: AggregateMetric<T>
        ): List<DataRecord> {
            val data = mutableListOf<DataRecord>()
            if (response != null) {
                response.sortedBy { it.startTime }
                var trackTime = startTime.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay()
                for (dailyResult in response) {
                    if (dailyResult.startTime.isAfter(trackTime)) {
                        while (trackTime.isBefore(dailyResult.startTime)) {
                            data.add(
                                DataRecord(
                                    metricValue = "No data",
                                    dataType = dataType,
                                    toDatetime = trackTime.toLocalDate().atTime(LocalTime.MAX)
                                        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dateTimeFormatter),
                                    fromDatetime = if (trackTime.toLocalDate().isEqual(startTime.toLocalDate()))
                                        startTime.format(dateTimeFormatter) else trackTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dateTimeFormatter)
                                )
                            )
                            trackTime = trackTime.plusDays(1)
                        }
                    }
                    val totalValue = dailyResult.result[metric]
                    data.add(
                        DataRecord(
                            metricValue = (totalValue ?: "No data").toString(),
                            dataType = dataType,
                            toDatetime = dailyResult.endTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).minusSeconds(1).format(dateTimeFormatter),
                            fromDatetime = if (dailyResult.startTime.toLocalDate().isEqual(startTime.toLocalDate()))
                                startTime.format(dateTimeFormatter) else dailyResult.startTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dateTimeFormatter)
                        )
                    )
                    trackTime = dailyResult.endTime
                }
                while (trackTime.isBefore(endTime.toLocalDateTime()) && between(trackTime, endTime).toMinutes() > 1) {
                    data.add(
                        DataRecord(
                            metricValue = "No data",
                            dataType = dataType,
                            toDatetime = if (trackTime.toLocalDate().isEqual(endTime.toLocalDate()))
                                endTime.format(dateTimeFormatter) else trackTime.toLocalDate().atTime(LocalTime.MAX)
                                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dateTimeFormatter),
                            fromDatetime = if (trackTime.toLocalDate().isEqual(startTime.toLocalDate()))
                                startTime.format(dateTimeFormatter) else trackTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dateTimeFormatter)
                        )
                    )
                    trackTime = trackTime.plusDays(1).toLocalDate().atStartOfDay()
                }
            }
            Log.d("HealthConnectUtils", "Parsed Data: $data")
            return data
        }


        suspend fun writeStepsData(context: Context, steps: Int, startTime: ZonedDateTime, endTime: ZonedDateTime) {
            val stepsRecord = StepsRecord(
                count = steps.toLong(),
                startTime = startTime.toInstant(),
                startZoneOffset = startTime.offset,
                endTime = endTime.toInstant(),
                endZoneOffset = endTime.offset
            )

            val response = healthConnectClient?.insertRecords(listOf(stepsRecord))

            if (response != null) {
                Log.d("HealthConnectUtils", "Steps data written successfully: $response")
            } else {
                Log.e("HealthConnectUtils", "Failed to write steps data.")
            }
        }
}

